# Sinusoidal waveform generator from DC

Tags: operational-amplifier, wien-bridge

I am working on a project which requires me to create some sinusoidal signals at specific frequencies using a DC battery as the only power input. And I also want to tune the amplitude of the output sine wave lets say minimum -5/+5 Volts. To achieve that, I made some research and found that Wien-Bridge oscillator might be the solution. However, I cannot be sure that whether it can accomplish given requirements I mentioned above or not.

Does it take its input as DC?
Can I tune its output amplitude easily?

And if it is not the solution I was looking, how can I get sinusoidal signals only using DC sources?

Comment: You are speaking of "sinusoidal signals"....be aware that this is an ideal case, Each oscillator output ("called "sinusoidal") will exhibit non-linear distortions, which strongly depend on the amplitude control mechanism within the oscillator. Hence, it is important if you have any signal quality requirements?

Comment: Actually i tried some circuits and most top and bottom parts of the sine waves were little bit clipped like 0.2 V. So that should be considered normal?

Comment: It is - more or less - "normal" without any additional means for amplitude control. If you can live with it - OK. Otherwise, you must use some non-linear elements (diodes for example) which can perform "soft limiting" (instead of hard-limiting resp. clipping caused by the power rail).

Comment: @LvW thanks, any recommendations on amplitude stability without too much effort and resources?

Comment: The most simple method is to make the feedback resistor RF of the gain stage somewhat larger than calculated (gain >3) and to place a series combination of another large resistor RP and two antiparallel diodes in parallel to RF. A rising amplitude will open the diodes an makes RF||RP and will the gain bring back to "3".

Comment: @LvW I have heard and seen that method too while researching, however one part I cannot understand about this solution, why those diodes be close at any time? The voltage on the RF looks like to be higher than 0.7V for almost all the times.

Comment: Buth this does not mean that the voltage across the diodes is also 0,7volts....don`t forget the relatively large resistor RP in series to the diodes...

Comment: @LvW so you mean a diode + 1Mohm resistor in series for which value of the potential between two ends(res+diode) the diode starts to allow the current? Because for me, the answer is idealy above 0.7 volts it starts to act as short.

Comment: I did not mention 1Mohm.....the goal is that RP||RF reaches the required value (for a gain of 3) for an output amplitude of some volts. You may start perhaps with RP=10*RF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any sinusoidal oscillator generates a sine wave from a DC input. That's what oscillators do. (Though not all oscillators generate sine waves - many of them generate different types of waves)

The amplitude of the Wien bridge oscillator is not easily controllable. You could build an amplifier with adjustable gain, after the oscillator, to control the amplitude of the output signal. Since your minimum amplitude is 5 volts, you could also try adjusting the oscillator's power supply voltage, if the voltage range suits the power supply of your op-amp.

Comment: What about using a voltage divider at the output?

Comment: That also works. The output impedance will be higher.

Comment: what do you mean by output impedance will be higher? Aren't output impedances of opamps low? In the range of 100 ohms maybe.

Comment: @muyustan yes but the output impedance of a voltage divider is high.

Comment: ok, so is it logical to load a speaker of 8 ohms to a voltage divider network consisting of a 100k pot wired to ground and a 100k fixed resistor and output taken from the potentiometer?

Comment: @muyustan Do the maths yourself. Don't forget the speaker is a resistor.